# Read evtx log files from win server 2008

Tags: .net-3.5, logging, windows-xp, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to read, from XP SP3, .evtx log files which are hosted on a windows 2008 server.

I use EventLogQuery, EventLogInformation which are in Framework 3.5 System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.

However Visual Studio tells me this: "platform not supported exception".
I don't get it as I have the Framework 3.5 installed already.

I am missing something here.

If anyone has a clue or another way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code for these classes constains the following line: (In NativeWrapper.cs)

```
private static bool s_platformNotSupported 
     = (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6);
```

In other words, they cannot be used on XP.

The [MSDN docs for the underlying native APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) state that it requires Vista or higher.

Comment: thanks SLaks.

that was pretty clear and obvious on msdn but i didn't came across 
it before.

i'll try to find a workaround as i can't change my OS.

still if anyone as a clue on how to do it from XP, i'll apreciate.

Wallou

Comment: @wallou: Actually, it's not obvious.  The docs for the managed classes incorrectly state that it works on XP SP3.